Rust API to conditionally run a closure on struct?
I've just created a trait + blanket implementation containing functions that apply a closure to a value given the value of a second parameter is true. I'm new to Rust and wonder what would be needed to cover "all" related behavior. That being

maybe I want the closure to only get a reference
... a mutable reference
... consume the value

And perhaps but I'm not sure I should also consider the (to me) subtle differences between

FnOnce
FnMut
Fn

Or maybe I also wish to pass two closures, so that first is the actual operation and the other is also passed the same parameter but only to compute the predicate to determine whether or not to apply the first. Again, this would need to provide all sensible combinations, such that the predicate does not consume the input value.
For all of this, I wonder if there are guidelines to determine which of these would make sense to place in the same trait, and which to separate, so that a maximum of types can be extended with this functionality.
This could probably also make sense on an iterator.
Also of interest, since I think these functions will potentially be available on almost anything, would be an intelligent naming scheme, to avoid collisions. Is there a standard to follow?
Is there anything important to consider to improve performance? Would make sense to mark these functions for inlining?
This all comes down to questions about good API design in Rust, so a detailed answer could, I believe, provide a lot of value to newcomers, even though this is a very brought question.
Here's what I have so far:
// trait definition with default implementation
trait ApplyIf
where
    Self: Sized + Clone,
{
    fn apply_if(self, modifier: impl Fn(Self) -> Self, condition: bool) -> Self {
        if condition {
            modifier(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }

    fn cloned_apply_if(self: &Self, modifier: impl Fn(&Self) -> Self, condition: bool) -> Self {
        if condition {
            modifier(self)
        } else {
            self.clone()
        }
    }
}

// blanket implementation
impl<T: Sized + Clone> ApplyIf for T {}

// usage
fn double_odds(val: usize) -> usize {
    val.apply_if(|v| v * 2, val % 2 == 1)
}


What's nice about it is that you can chain the apply_if calls. I used it for formatting / colorizing terminal output. An example of such usage would be
fn do_many_things_conditionally(val: usize) -> usize {
    val
        .apply_if(|v| v * 2, val % 2 == 1)
        .apply_if(|v| v * 5, val % 5 == 3)
        .apply_if(|v| v / 3, val % 9 == 0)
}


Removing and reposting part of the question to circumvent closure is not the way to go, requests to help find a library are explicitly off topic anyways.

Your implementation is cool as it is. But I would split it into 2 traits, so that for the first function, the Clone is not required

@cafce25 Removing and reposting part of the question to circumvent closure because the original question was two questions in one seems quite the way to go to me. You are right that apparently bluntly asking for a crate is considered off-topic. Let me rephrase it again so it makes more sense here, since I'm convinced that there is something stackoverflow worthy in here ;)

I've changed the question to not ask for a crate but ask about all the subtleties I'd hoped a crate might answer in code. I'm not sure you'll like this one better. If nobody wants to answer this, I'll probably research it myself and try to answer it later. If you still feel this is not an appropriate question, feel free to vote to close it. But perhaps you could then point me to better places where I might find answers / ask for crates?

You can ask for libraries at SoftwareRecs SE, but make sure your question meets their guidelines. You can ask about ways to improve your working code on CodeReview SE (and from my judgement this question would be a great fit there, as currently written). StackOverflow is for specific problems - not necessarily like compile or runtime errors, of course, but something narrowly scoped and not achieving the intended goal (be it wrong answer or, say, too low performance - quantifiable)

I've done my research. Specifically, I've looked into the tap crate for inspiration. In the following, I will highlight what I learned.


maybe I want the closure to only get a reference
... a mutable reference
... consume the value


These are all valid concerns, but Rust's type system lets us go even further by writing versions that work with central traits like Borrow<T>, BorrowMut<T>, AsRef<T>, AsMut<T>, Deref<T> and DerefMut<T>, adding a lot more flexibility than just to accept a (mutable) reference.

And perhaps but I'm not sure I should also consider the (to me) subtle
differences between

FnOnce
FnMut
Fn


Here, basically, FnOnce is the easiest to write (any closure is FnOnce), but also the most restrictive (can't be used everywhere). When designing an API, try work with FnOnce if you can (which is, most notably, if you only need to call it once) and use FnMut and Fn if you must. This gives maximum flexibility to users of your API. For apply_if and friends, FnOnce is always possible.

Or maybe I also wish to pass two closures, so that first is the actual
operation and the other is also passed the same parameter but only to
compute the predicate to determine whether or not to apply the first.
Again, this would need to provide all sensible combinations, such that
the predicate does not consume the input value.

This may provide value in certain cases, notably if you can re-use that second closure across calls to apply_if. However, this is a niche use case, and we clutter up the namespace of functions defined on almost all types with those blanket implementations. Perhaps move this into another trait, which doesn't have to be brought into scope.

For all of this, I wonder if there are guidelines to determine which
of these would make sense to place in the same trait, and which to
separate, so that a maximum of types can be extended with this
functionality.

Next to the aforementioned namespace cluttering, mostly group your functions by the trait bounds they require. That ensures all of them can be implemented for the maximum number of possible types.

This could probably also make sense on an iterator.

Honestly, by now I think that hurts the single responsibility principle. Iterators have all the functions they need. If you want this, do it. But do it in a separate trait.

Also of interest, since I think these functions will potentially be
available on almost anything, would be an intelligent naming scheme,
to avoid collisions. Is there a standard to follow?

I think this needs to be determined on a case-by-case basis. In this case, I decided to go with pipe_if and tap_if instead of apply_if, because the popular tap crate uses pipe and tap and I wanted to align with that. I've also explicitly chosen the naming scheme tap_<variant>_if, so a user can type tap and get suggestions for all available tapping functions easily.

Is there anything important to consider to improve performance? Would
make sense to mark these functions for inlining?

These are short, often used functions - a prime example for inlining. The tap crate marks all its functions for inlining, so I think it's a good idea.
So here's the full code I've come up with so far:
use std::{
    borrow::{Borrow, BorrowMut},
    ops::{Deref, DerefMut},
};

use tap::{Conv, Pipe};

// Originally, I thought this might be a good idea, but all these cases
// are already covered by the `Borrow<T>` and friends implementations,
// so now I think this can go
pub trait TapIf {
    fn tap_refborrow_if<B>(self: &Self, condition: bool, runner: impl FnOnce(&B)) -> &Self
    where
        Self: Borrow<B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        if condition {
            runner(self.borrow());
        };
        self
    }

    fn tap_refborrow_mut_if<B>(
        self: &mut Self,
        condition: bool,
        modifier: impl FnOnce(&mut B),
    ) -> &mut Self
    where
        Self: BorrowMut<B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        if condition {
            modifier(self.borrow_mut());
        };
        self
    }

    fn tap_refborrow_if_fulfills(
        self: &Self,
        predicate: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
        runner: impl FnOnce(&Self),
    ) -> &Self {
        self.tap_refborrow_if(predicate(self), runner)
    }

    fn tap_refborrow_mut_if_fulfills(
        self: &mut Self,
        predicate: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
        modifier: impl FnOnce(&mut Self),
    ) -> &mut Self {
        self.tap_refborrow_mut_if(predicate(self), modifier)
    }
}

/// Defines utilities to conditionally tap closures to values in a chainable fashion.
pub trait TapIfSized
where
    Self: Sized,
{
    fn pipe_if(self, condition: bool, modifier: impl FnOnce(Self) -> Self) -> Self {
        if condition {
            modifier(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }

    fn tap_if(self, condition: bool, runner: impl FnOnce(&Self)) -> Self {
        if condition {
            runner(&self);
        }
        self
    }

    fn tap_borrow_if<B>(self, condition: bool, runner: impl FnOnce(&B)) -> Self
    where
        Self: Borrow<B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        if condition {
            runner(self.borrow());
        }
        self
    }

    fn tap_borrow_mut_if<B>(mut self, condition: bool, runner: impl FnOnce(&mut B)) -> Self
    where
        Self: BorrowMut<B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        if condition {
            runner(self.borrow_mut());
        }
        self
    }

    fn tap_ref_if<B>(self, condition: bool, runner: impl FnOnce(&B)) -> Self
    where
        Self: AsRef<B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        if condition {
            runner(self.as_ref());
        }
        self
    }

    fn tap_ref_mut_if<B>(mut self, condition: bool, runner: impl FnOnce(&mut B)) -> Self
    where
        Self: AsMut<B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        if condition {
            runner(self.as_mut());
        }
        self
    }

    fn tap_deref_if<B>(self, condition: bool, runner: impl FnOnce(&B)) -> Self
    where
        Self: Deref<Target = B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        if condition {
            runner(&self);
        }
        self
    }

    fn tap_deref_mut_if<B>(mut self, condition: bool, runner: impl FnOnce(&mut B)) -> Self
    where
        Self: DerefMut + Deref<Target = B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        if condition {
            runner(&mut self);
        }
        self
    }

    // better move this to its own trait
    fn pipe_if_fulfills(
        self,
        predicate: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
        modifier: impl FnOnce(Self) -> Self,
    ) -> Self {
        predicate(&self).pipe(|condition| self.pipe_if(condition, modifier))
    }

    fn tap_if_fulfills(
        self,
        predicate: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
        runner: impl FnOnce(&Self),
    ) -> Self {
        predicate(&self).pipe(|condition| self.tap_if(condition, runner))
    }

    fn tap_borrow_if_fulfills<B>(
        self,
        predicate: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
        modifier: impl FnOnce(&B),
    ) -> Self
    where
        Self: Borrow<B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        predicate(&self).pipe(|condition| self.tap_borrow_if(condition, modifier))
    }

    fn tap_borrow_mut_if_fulfills<B>(
        self,
        predicate: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
        modifier: impl FnOnce(&mut B),
    ) -> Self
    where
        Self: BorrowMut<B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        predicate(&self).pipe(|condition| self.tap_borrow_mut_if(condition, modifier))
    }

    fn tap_ref_if_fulfills<B>(
        self,
        predicate: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
        modifier: impl FnOnce(&B),
    ) -> Self
    where
        Self: AsRef<B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        predicate(&self).pipe(|condition| self.tap_ref_if(condition, modifier))
    }

    fn tap_ref_mut_if_fulfills<B>(
        self,
        predicate: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
        modifier: impl FnOnce(&mut B),
    ) -> Self
    where
        Self: AsMut<B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        predicate(&self).pipe(|condition| self.tap_ref_mut_if(condition, modifier))
    }

    fn tap_deref_if_fulfills<B>(
        self,
        predicate: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
        runner: impl FnOnce(&B),
    ) -> Self
    where
        Self: Deref<Target = B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        predicate(&self).pipe(|condition| self.tap_deref_if(condition, runner))
    }

    fn tap_deref_mut_if_fulfills<B>(
        self,
        predicate: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
        runner: impl FnOnce(&mut B),
    ) -> Self
    where
        Self: DerefMut + Deref<Target = B>,
        B: ?Sized,
    {
        predicate(&self).pipe(|condition| self.tap_deref_mut_if(condition, runner))
    }
}

// This was another experiment. I think this too goes a bit far and
// conflicts with the single responsibility principle.
// Clone your values yourself!
pub trait TapIfCloned
where
    Self: Sized + Clone,
{
    fn pipe_cloned_if(self: &Self, condition: bool, modifier: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> Self) -> Self {
        if condition {
            modifier(self)
        } else {
            self.clone()
        }
    }

    fn pipe_cloned_if_fulfills(
        self: &Self,
        predicate: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
        modifier: impl FnOnce(&Self) -> Self,
    ) -> Self {
        self.pipe_cloned_if(predicate(self), modifier)
    }
}

impl<T> TapIf for T {}
impl<T: Sized> TapIfSized for T {}
impl<T: Sized + Clone> TapIfCloned for T {}


Edit: now that you mentioned tap crate, It does make much more sense to implement for other types Because originally I thought this was only for mutating the original value when met the condition, At least that's what the function's name and examples implied (to me). Secondly i am not sure about FnOnce but hey you do you.

I've just created a trait + blanket implementation containing functions that apply a closure to a value given the value of a second parameter is true. I'm new to Rust and wonder what would be needed to cover "all" related behavior. That being maybe I want the closure to only get a reference ... a mutable reference ... consume the value

since you're going to modify the value, you only need to implement for mutable, implementing for references don't make sense at all, same with consuming the value.

Or maybe I also wish to pass two closures, so that first is the actual operation and the other is also passed the same parameter but only to compute the predicate to determine whether or not to apply the first. Again, this would need to provide all sensible combinations, such that the predicate does not consume the input value

I am not sure if i understand it correctly, but that's just over complicating things.

For all of this, I wonder if there are guidelines to determine which of these would make sense to place in the same trait, and which to separate, so that a maximum of types can be extended with this functionality.

experience I suppose

Also of interest, since I think these functions will potentially be available on almost anything, would be an intelligent naming scheme, to avoid collisions. Is there a standard to follow?

sorry to break your enthusiasm, implementing this to everything, seems again like over complicating things, the convenience of using it, is just not worth the effort, plus the if else statements are already flexible enough, no need to re-invent the wheel. btw ApplyIf is unique enough, won't cause any collisions

Is there anything important to consider to improve performance? Would make sense to mark these functions for inlining?

if you're turning it into a crate, then you probably should inline everything, other wise if it's an executable the compiler will automatically inline, if it sees fit. Secondly you should avoid .clone() as much as possible.

This all comes down to questions about good API design in Rust, so a detailed answer could, I believe, provide a lot of value to newcomers, even though this is a very brought question.

A good Api design is needed when you have a sophisticated API, and I am afraid this isn't.
before we get to the last questions, here the "better" implementation
trait ApplyIf 
where
    Self: Sized
{
    fn apply_if<F>(&mut self, modifier: F, condition: bool) -> &mut Self     
    where
        F: Fn(&mut Self) -> &mut Self,
    {
        if condition { 
            modifier(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

// usage 
let mut a = 10;
a.apply_if(|x| { *x += 1; x }, true);


And perhaps but I'm not sure I should also consider the (to me) subtle differences between FnOnce, FnMut, Fn

Fn FnMut FnOnce are just the status of closure, or level of access they have over their environment. for example Fn closures can only reference from it's environment,
example:
let mut env_var = 0;
let _: impl Fn() = || {
    println!("{}", env_var);
    env_var = 10; // this won't be possible; 
}

but FnMut closures can have mutable references from it's environment
let mut env_var = 0;
let _: impl FnMut() = || {
    println!("{}", env_var);
    env_var = 10; // this is ok 
}

and FnOnce will consume the variables

thank you very much for your effort. Unfortunately, I consider your answer a bit too shallow to count it as the solution. Some things I believe are also not fully correct. I've done some research in the meantime and will post my own answer. Then, the community can decide which one is better
